# Why does SSH mode for emacs (ssh-el) hang?

Tags: microsoft-windows, ssh

Adding this for anyone who runs into this problem.

I use [SSH mode for emacs (ssh-el)](https://github.com/ieure/ssh-el) on Windows and it just hangs there without connecting sometimes, usually after a crash.

Comment: It's probably not relevant to the issue described here, but if you'd rather run your ssh sessions inside `ansi-term` you might find the `my-ssh` command at http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/18678 useful as an alternative to ssh-el.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open task manager and quit all ssh.exe processes you see.

When emacs crashes on Windows and it's using ssh-el the ssh process keeps running and blocks emacs from connecting. Rebooting would probably also work.