# Ansi-Term not reading .profile

Tags: shell, ansi-term, bash, exec-path

my question is very similar to [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20733/load-my-profile-for-bash-in-emacs-terminal-buffer-multi-term-mode).

I use my `.profile` file to set environment variables, such as `EDITOR`.  However, when I run `ansi-term` and type `printenv` I can see that that variable is not defined.

I am already using `exec-path-from-shell` but it looks like certain environment variables are not set.

Apparently the `.profile` file is only supposed to be read on login, but this means that environment variables that I do need to be set are not set for `ansi-term` which is my preferred way to use a shell in emacs.

Simply put I am looking for a way to make the environment in `ansi-term` identical to the a login shell.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Normally `.profile` is read on login, and so your environment variables would be set in Emacs (and therefore in all Emacs subprocesses including the ones started from ansi-term). If your environment variables aren't set in Emacs then there's something wrong with your system configuration, it isn't Emacs fault. Are you running OSX? It manages user sessions differently; if you're running OSX you should look at OSX documentation/tutorials to see how to set environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

> Apparently the .profile file is only supposed to be read on login

Correct. Invariably there are other shell resource files which are read on non-login shell invocations, however.

If your shell is `bash` then you can use `~/.bashrc` for this, and including something like the following in your `~/.profile` is then fairly common if you want your non-login settings to be used in your login shells as well:

```sh
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

You should read the `INVOCATION` section of the bash man page for full details. In Emacs you can use <kbd>g</kbd> `INVOCATION` in the man page buffer, after <kbd>M-x</kbd> `man` <kbd>RET</kbd> `bash` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Of course if your shell is something different, you should check *its* man page for the relevant details.

Comment: So, to put it simply I am looking for a way to make `ansi-term` behave just like a login shell, is that possible?

Comment: Well firstly `ansi-term` is a terminal emulator, not a shell. You can run a program inside it (e.g. `bash`), but by default you cannot pass command-line arguments to that program (e.g. `bash -l` would be useful, as that tells bash to act like a login shell), so you would need to write a wrapper command to do this (either an elisp command, or a shell script which invoked your shell with the desired arguments).

Comment: Refer to https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/18672 regarding writing elisp wrapper commands for running alternative programs (possibly with command line options) in a term buffer.

Comment: If you wish to instead provide a shell script which invokes `bash -l` or similar, then you can manipulate the *default* program suggested by `ansi-term` by setting any of the following: `explicit-shell-file-name` variable; `ESHELL` environment variable; `SHELL` environment variable.

Comment: setting `explicit-shell-file-name` seems to only work when I call `shell` not ansi-term.  Additionally it doesn't seem to accept the `-l` option.

Comment: Maybe your version of Emacs doesn't look for that variable then. It works for 24.4+ at least. And yes, as I mentioned before, you *cannot* specify command line options in the `program` argument to `ansi-term`.